# How to get VmSize in powershell on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

I want to write VmSize. When i type `get-azvm` i have all information about VM.

When i type `get-azvm |select VmSize` i have an empty variable.
How can i get this only this information?

I search information in web I only find how to get info about disk in localization.

[image: I need the VmSize]

```
PS C:\>Windows\system32> get-azvm

ResourceGroupName           Name   Location          VmSize  OsType            NIC ProvisioningState Zone
-----------------           ----   --------          ------  ------            --- ----------------- ----
WITRG             maszynatestowa westeurope Standard_D2s_v3 Windows maszynatestowa         Succeeded     
WITRG2                     Druga westeurope Standard_DS1_v2 Windows       druga783         Succeeded     
WITRG2                    WitVM2 westeurope Standard_D2s_v3 Windows         WitVM2         Succeeded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-AzVM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HardwareProfile
```

**Documentation:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm

Comment: Get-AzVM : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ExpandProperty'.
At line:1 char:10
+ Get-AzVM -ExpandProperty HardwareProfile
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzVM], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMCommand

Comment: Yes, there was pipe and select missing. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution
`Get-AzVM |select -ExpandProperty HardwareProfile`